# Calculate the flow velocity with only knowing DP and pipe diameter

Tags: pressure, velocity

I have an air blower and I blow this air in a cylindrical line but i dont know the velocity of air i can arrange the velocity with this blowing machine but it doesnt give me a number so i want to calculate it. I have 2 pressure instrument that means i can calculate the p0 and p1 in a specific length of in this pipe. You can see the illustration in attachment.
Important note: air is just a example it is mixed fluid we cannot know it's viscosity :)
[image]

Comment: Without the viscoscity, even   knowing that the flow is laminar, you do not have enough information to find $v$.

Comment: What is "L" and what is the pressure drop?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Actually we dont know the numerical value yet.But if we can solve how can we calculate we will put 2 Pressure instrument and will know about the p0 and p1. and L is(Length between the two pressure instrument p0 and p1)

Comment: i just think about the bernouli principle, if we place one orifice in pipe and 2 pressure instruments can we say the DP square root equals to velocity? What do you think?